# Call render method of second js file in backbone js

Tags: backbone.js

I have two different backbone js file for 2 different view. I need to call the render method of the second js file from the first one. How can i do that

I have one backbone.js file which as a view called DocumentsPageView. In my second backbone js file when i click button on the first js file i have to call the render method of DocumentsPageview

### first js file

```
first.backbonejs = (function($) {
    case myapp  
        sectionView = new second.mysecondbackbone.DocumentsPageView();
        sectionView.render();
        break;
    }
}(jQuery)
```

### second js file

```
second.mysecondbackbone = (function($) {
    var DocumentsPageView= Backbone.View.extend({
        render: function(){
            //render the page
        }
    });
}(jQuery)
```

I am getting object undefined in the declaration section

Thanks & Regards
Ashik

Answer (score 0):

My advice is, don't.

Use a mediator object that sits between the two, and controls the process of working with both views.

It can be as simple as this:

```
myProcess = {

  show: function(){
    var view1 = new View1();
    view1.on("foo", this.doMoreStuff, this);
    this.showView(view1);
  },

  doMoreStuff: function(){
    var view2 = new View2();
    this.showView(view2);
  },

  showView: function(view){
    // code to stuff view.$el in to the DOM
  }

}
```

The advantage here is that you have a high level workflow that can be managed and maintained on it's own, separate from the implementation details of the individual views. You don't have to trace down in to the individual views to see how they work together.

I wrote more about this, here: http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2012/05/10/modeling-explicit-workflow-with-code-in-javascript-and-backbone-apps/

Comment: But i want to include the second view inside the first view. ie, when i click a button on the first view i have to call a view that is declared in another backbone js file

Comment: ah, ok. very different than what I thought you were asking. you should update the question to reflect the specifics of what you want. I'll delete this answer after you've updated the question.